# Adafruit GFX: cannot display text and bitmap at the same time

Tags: arduino-ide, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit

I have Adafruit RP2040 Feather with DVI. I am using Arduino IDE and Adafruit GFX library.
I have short program that displays a 8-bit bitmap. I would like to display some text and the bitmap at the same time. I cannot figure out how. The program below, when executing, displays bitmap then goes blank for 2 secs and then the bitmap again.
How come the text is not being displayed?

```
#include <PicoDVI.h>
#include "sprites.h" // Graphics data

DVIGFX8 display(DVI_RES_320x240p60, true, adafruit_feather_dvi_cfg);


void setup() { // Runs once on startup
  if (!display.begin()) { // Blink LED if insufficient RAM
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    for (;;) digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, (millis() / 500) & 1);
  }

  // Initialize color palette from table in sprites.h. Rather than
  // calling setColor() for each one, we can just dump it directly...
  memcpy(display.getPalette(), palette, sizeof palette);

}


void loop() {

  display.fillScreen(20);               // Clear back framebuffer,

  display.setFont();                   // Use default font
  display.setCursor(0, 10);            // Initial cursor position
  display.setTextSize(1);              // Default size
  display.println(F("TEXT 1"));
  delay(2000);

  display.drawGrayscaleBitmap(0, display.height() - 125, BINGO, 125, 125);
  display.swap();  // bitmap is visible after swap 
  delay(2000);

}
```

I've tried various combinations of display.swap(). I can either display text or bitmap, but not both at the same time. What am I doing wrong?